# bufferedReader.read() is blocking but only on some devices

Tags: java, android, sockets

I built an app to send data to an server and the server is responding an response.
The app works perfectly on all Samsung devices.
I assumed that it was finished, but then I got a new phone, pocophone F1 by Xiaomi.
It works 50/50 on first time but 2nd time it is blocking at .read() / .readline() (answer containing /r/n).
Then is started to try others and it doesn't work also on huawei.

How can I debug why exactly read() is blocking?

On Samsung it works 100/100 times.
On others it is 2/100 times and much slower to reach .read() not -1.

A question about the server:
(Maybe I am doing it wrong there)
Do I have to close the socket after sending the response?
(I don't want to have a live connection, just ask for response get response done.)
At the moment I close the socket on client side if finished reading.
(But said above sometimes it never finished or reach .read()).

Comment: You should close the socket on server side after finishing writing the data. Same on client side after finishing reading the data.

Comment: Ok thank you, then I will try this. Strange is that it works some times...

Answer (score 1):

As i understand - you are performing reading from socket in a separate `Thread` - if you dont - you should. 
When have completed to read from socket - you can either:

- call `socket.close` from other thread - this will unclock all threads that are blocked on `read` from socket
- interrupt thread - this will make `read` method to throw `InterruptedException` - make sure you are handling it properly

Alternatively - your server can close connection

Comment: Yes I am doing it in DoInBackround Thread. Thanks for your answer this sounds good. And good to know the interrupt thing. Regards.